# How to call External .dll in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Can anyone here show me how can I call external dll file in Delphi?

Comment: What are you tried, so far?

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow is not a site where you can expect people to convert your code for you. You should try to do it yourself, and if you get stuck, then ask specific questions about where you're stuck.

Comment: Our "time and effort" costs you some "time and effort" as well. you should try and learn a little Delphi instead of asking people to do things for you. If that's your general attitude towards things, good luck with life.

Comment: I just asked how to call external .dll in delphi. Tha was all.

Comment: @Barlet: No, you asked how to translate this VB.NET code into Delphi.  If "how to call an external DLL in Delphi" is what you're looking for, then that would probably be a lot better received.  Try editing your question and rephrasing it like that, and you'll probably get some good answers.

Comment: This code is kind of weird. One bit uses p/invoke, the other old-school VB6 `Declare`. It's really easy to port to Delphi.

Comment: And my comment no longer makes sense since the code was removed from the original question.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation covers this topic here: [Procedures and Functions, External Declarations](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions#External_Declarations).

As an example, the documentation shows how to link to the Windows API function `MessageBox`:

```
function MessageBox(
    hWnd: HWND; 
    lpText: PWideChar;
    lpCaption: PWideChar; 
    uType: UINT
 ): Integer; stdcall; external 'user32.dll' name 'MessageBoxW';
```

*Note: I corrected the multitude of errors in the documentation's declaration of this function.*

Comment: That's a very bad example in the help indeed! Amazing you can make that many errors in one example!

Comment: @Remko, I suspect that documentation hasn't changed much since Delphi 2. At that time, the declaration would have been correct — Delphi didn't have unsigned 32-bit types back then, so HWnd, UInt, and Integer were all equivalent types.

Comment: @Rob It was wrong even then. HWND is semantically different from an int. Failing to use the semantically accurate type is what leads to 64 bit pointer truncation bugs. Given that the horrows of Win16 to Win32 would have been fresh in the minds of D2 devs, getting that stuff right should not have been hard.